# The eigenvalues of an 'assembled' Hadamard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure whether this title makes sense, but...

---

- Let's say $\mathbf H$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix whose component is either +1 or -1.
- Let's say $\mathbf Z$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix whose component is entirely 0.

Now suppose that I assemble these matrices in a 'bipartite graph' fashion

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Z} & \mathbf{H} \\ \mathbf{H}' & \mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{H}'$ is a transpose of $\mathbf H$. As $\mathbf A$ is a real symmetric $2n\times 2n$ matrix, it has $2n$ real eigenvalues. And as it is in the form of 'adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph', eigenvalues come as a pair; that is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$ if and only if so is $-\lambda$.

---

I'm playing with the eigenvalues of this matrix and it seems the following property holds.

> The [spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix) (set of eigenvalues) of $\mathbf A$ has $n$ copies of $-\sqrt n$ and $n$ copies of $\sqrt n$ if and only if the matrix $\mathbf H$ is a [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) satysfying $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}'=n\mathbf{I}$.

Is this *conjecture* true? If it is, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
A:=\pmatrix{0&B\\B^*&0}
$$
and $B=USV^*$ is the SVD of $B$, then
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&USV^*\\VSU^*&0}
=\pmatrix{U&0\\0&V}\pmatrix{0&S\\S&0}\pmatrix{U&0\\0&V}^*,
$$
that is, $A$ is unitarily similar to the matrix $S$
$$
C:=\pmatrix{0&S\\S&0},
$$
where $S:=\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ is diagonal. You can verify that
$$
C\pmatrix{e_i\\e_i}=\sigma_i\pmatrix{e_i\\e_i}, \quad
C\pmatrix{e_i\\-e_i}=-\sigma_i\pmatrix{e_i\\-e_i},
$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$th column of the $n\times n$ identity,
so the matrix $C$ (and hence $A$) has the eigenvalues $\pm\sigma_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

So the spectrum of $A$ has the eigenvalues $-\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ (each of the multiplicity $n$) if and only if $S:=\sqrt{n}I$, that is, $B=\sqrt{n}UV^*$ for some unitary $U$ and $V$ from which it follows that $B=\sqrt{n}Q$, where $Q$ is unitary (product of two unitary matrices is unitary and, on the other hand, each unitary matrix is a product of two unitary matrices, namely itself and the identity). If $BB^*=nI$, we have that $I=(\sqrt{n}^{-1}B)(\sqrt{n}^{-1}B)^*$ and consequently, $\sqrt{n}^{-1}B$ is unitary and hence $B=\sqrt{n}Q$ for some unitary $Q$.